# Redis vs MySQL for Financial Data?

Tags: mysql, redis

I realize that this question is pretty well discussed, however I would like to get your input in the context of my specific needs.

I am developing a realtime financial database that grabs stock quotes from the net multiple times a minute and stores it in a database. I am currently working with SQLAlchemy over MySQL, but I came across Redis and it looks interesting. It looks good especially because of its performance, which is crucial in my application. I know that MySQL can be fast too, I just feel like implementing heavy caching is going to be a pain.

The data I am saving is by far mostly decimal values. I am also doing a significant amount of divisions and multiplications with these decimal values (in a different application).

In terms of data size, I am grabbing about 10,000 symbols multiple times a minute. This amounts to about 3 TB of data a year.

I am also concerned by Redis's key quantity limitation (2^32). Is Redis a good solution here? What other factors can help me make the decision either toward MySQL or Redis?

Thank you!

Comment: MySQL is a relational database, whilst Redist is a key:value store. That alone should ring the bell on what to use. On Amazon RDS MySQL simply flies when it comes to reading and writing. If I were you (and had some cash to back the app up), I'd create it with MySQL and install on Amazon RDS.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Redis is an in-memory store. All the data must fit in memory. So except if you have 3 TB of RAM per year of data, it is not the right option. The 2^32 limit is not really an issue in practice, because you would probably have to shard your data anyway (i.e. use multiple instances), and because the limit is actually 2^32 keys *with* 2^32 items per key.

If you have enough memory and still want to use (sharded) Redis, here is how you can store space efficient time series: https://github.com/antirez/redis-timeseries

You may also want to patch Redis in order to add a proper time series data structure. See Luca Sbardella's implementation at:

https://github.com/lsbardel/redis

http://lsbardel.github.com/python-stdnet/contrib/redis_timeseries.html

Redis is excellent to aggregate statistics in real time and store the result of these caclulations (i.e. DIRT applications). However, storing historical data in Redis is much less interesting, since it offers no query language to perform offline calculations on these data. Btree based stores supporting sharding (MongoDB for instance) are probably more convenient than Redis to store large time series.

Traditional relational databases are not so bad to store time series. People have dedicated entire books to this topic:

[Developing Time-Oriented Database Applications in SQL](http://www.cs.arizona.edu/people/rts/tdbbook.pdf)

Another option you may want to consider is using a bigdata solution:

[storing massive ordered time series data in bigtable derivatives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1623399/storing-massive-ordered-time-series-data-in-bigtable-derivatives)

IMO the main point (whatever the storage engine) is to evaluate the access patterns to these data. What do you want to use these data for? How will you access these data once they have been stored? Do you need to retrieve all the data related to a given symbol? Do you need to retrieve the evolution of several symbols in a given time range? Do you need to correlate values of different symbols by time? etc ...

My advice is to try to list all these access patterns. The choice of a given storage mechanism will only be a consequence of this analysis.

Regarding MySQL usage, I would definitely consider [table partitioning](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/partitioning.html) because of the volume of the data. Depending on the access patterns, I would also consider the [ARCHIVE engine](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/archive-storage-engine.html). This engine stores data in compressed flat files. It is space efficient. It can be used with partitioning, so despite it does not index the data, it can be efficient at retrieving a subset of data if the partition granularity is carefully chosen.

Comment: thank you for your response. with respect to MySQL, what concepts or features should I look into to optimize my use of MySQL?

Comment: redis timeseries library is outdated now, might wanna update your answer

Answer (score 1):

You should consider Cassandra or Hbase. Both allow contiguous storage and fast appends, so that when it comes to querying, you get huge performance. Both will easily ingest tens of thousands of points per second.

The key point is along one of your query dimensions (usually by ticker), you're accessing disk (ssd or spinning), *contiguously*. You're not having to hit indices millions of times. You can model things in Mongo/SQL to get similar performance, but it's more hassle, and you get it "for free" out of the box with the columnar guys, without having to do any client side shenanigans to merge blobs together.

My experience with Cassandra is that it's 10x faster than MongoDB, which is already much faster than most relational databases, for the time series use case, and as data size grows, its advantage over the others grows too. That's true even on a single machine. [Here](https://academy.datastax.com/demos/getting-started-time-series-data-modeling) is where you should start.

The only negative on Cassandra at least is that you don't have consistency for a few seconds sometimes if you have a big cluster, so you need either to force it, slowing it down, or you accept that the very very latest print *sometimes* will be a few seconds old. On a single machine there will be zero consistency problems, and you'll get the same columnar benefits.

Less familiar with Hbase but it claims to be more consistent (there will be a cost elsewhere - CAP theorem), but it's much more of a commitment to setup the Hbase stack.

Answer (score 0):

You should first check the features that Redis offers in terms of data selection and aggregation. Compared to an SQL database, Redis is limited.

In fact, 'Redis vs MySQL' is usually not the right question, since they are apples and pears. If you are refreshing the data in your database (also removing regularly), check out MySQL partitioning. See e.g. the answer I wrote to [What is the best way to delete old rows from MySQL on a rolling basis?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9472167/what-is-the-best-way-to-delete-old-rows-from-mysql-on-a-rolling-basis)

>

Check out [MySQL Partitioning](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/partitioning-overview.html):

> Data that loses its usefulness can often be easily removed from a partitioned table by dropping the partition (or partitions) containing only that data. Conversely, the process of adding new data can in some cases be greatly facilitated by adding one or more new partitions for storing specifically that data.

See e.g. this post to get some ideas on how to apply it:

> [Using Partitioning and Event Scheduler to Prune Archive Tables](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/partitioning-event_scheduler.html)

And this one:

> [Partitioning by dates: the quick how-to](http://everythingmysql.ning.com/profiles/blogs/partitioning-by-dates-the)

Comment: Hy - thanks! I am not removing, just constantly adding and querying (no need to remove historical values, I actually need them). Is your response still relevant then?

Comment: The link on MySQL Partitioning contains some examples of queries that can benefit from partitioning. See also Partition Pruning: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/partitioning-pruning.html